# Prices in my Category column - Using RStudio

Tags: r, data-cleaning, analysis

[j_dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1inw.png)

Hi! Very new to R language. I have a dataset where there are some prices in my category_alias column. The issue cells are where the data is misplaced have null cells for where the data is supposed to be. I would like to move the prices into the right column but don't know where to start.

Here is a sample of what the data set looks like with the issue columns:

```
      Category_alias USD_Price
5350 jewelry.pendant    589.00
5351          427.07        NA
5352    jewelry.ring    495.21
5353                    447.89
5354 jewelry.earring    804.79
5355           53.62        NA
5356    jewelry.ring    509.59
5357 jewelry.earring    405.48
5358  jewelry.brooch    352.05
5359 jewelry.earring    587.67
5360 jewelry.pendant    158.70
5361    jewelry.ring    150.55
5362    jewelry.ring    214.48
5363    jewelry.ring     82.05
5364 jewelry.earring    280.68
5365 jewelry.pendant    212.19
```

dput() output:

```
structure(list(Category_alias = c("jewelry.pendant", "427.07", 
"jewelry.ring", "", "jewelry.earring", "53.62", "jewelry.ring", 
"jewelry.earring", "jewelry.brooch", "jewelry.earring", 
"jewelry.pendant", 
"jewelry.ring", "jewelry.ring", "jewelry.ring", 
"jewelry.earring", 
"jewelry.pendant"), USD_Price = c(589, NA, 495.21, 447.89, 
804.79, 
NA, 509.59, 405.48, 352.05, 587.67, 158.7, 150.55, 214.48, 82.05, 
280.68, 212.19)), row.names = 5350:5365, class = "data.frame")
```

I've searched for solutions but nothing I've found has been applicable.

Comment: Hi Cassidy! Could you edit your question to provide a little more clarity, what you've tried, why it didn't work (error? wrong output?), reproducible data, and expected output? See this helpful link for tips on [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also, please dont post data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12109788). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for editing Cassidy but the additional information was not helpful or reproducible. The tips in the link above will help, for instance something like editing your question to include `dput(j[1:25, c("Category_alias", "USD_Price")]`

Comment: thanks for the help @jpsmith! Hopefully I added all the info you were looking for now

Comment: Thanks for the `dput` output - that's very helpful for fixing your problem as it stands. I'd ask one more question first, though - how did you get this data into R? It's possible that a better place to fix the issue may be at the data import step. If this came from a CSV file or something like that, if you could post the first few rows of the file and the command you used to read it in to R, we might be able to fix it there.

Comment: Thanks Cassidy! Yes, this edit is very helpful. I agree with Gregor Thomas that the issue may be more upstream, as it seems like this is a systematic data issue (as opposed to a once-off data entry error). At any rate, you can solve the immediate issue in the sample data with some indexing - something like `j$USD_Price[is.na(j$USD_Price)] <- j$Category_alias[!is.na(as.numeric(j$Category_alias))]; j$Category_alias[!is.na(as.numeric(j$Category_alias))] <- NA; j` or an `ifelse` statement if you're more comfortable with those.

Comment: I used `options(scipen=999) j <- read.csv('jewelry.csv')`

Comment: I also tried `options(scipen=999) j <- read.csv(file = 'jewelry.csv', header = FALSE, sep = ',')` and got the same result. I've opened the file in excel when I first received it and the columns were also organized the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to copy those numbers over using `dplyr`. `coalesce` is a handy function for replacing missing values.

We get a warning about "NAs introduced by coercion" because we run `as.numeric()` on the `Category_alias` column, and (as expected) most of those values can't converted to numeric--so we know we're fine with ignoring the warning.

```
library(dplyr)
j = j |>
  mutate(USD_Price = coalesce(USD_Price, as.numeric(Category_alias))
  )
#       Category_alias USD_Price
# 5350 jewelry.pendant    589.00
# 5351          427.07    427.07
# 5352    jewelry.ring    495.21
# 5353                    447.89
# 5354 jewelry.earring    804.79
# 5355           53.62     53.62
# 5356    jewelry.ring    509.59
# 5357 jewelry.earring    405.48
# 5358  jewelry.brooch    352.05
# 5359 jewelry.earring    587.67
# 5360 jewelry.pendant    158.70
# 5361    jewelry.ring    150.55
# 5362    jewelry.ring    214.48
# 5363    jewelry.ring     82.05
# 5364 jewelry.earring    280.68
# 5365 jewelry.pendant    212.19
# Warning message:
# There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
# ℹ In argument: `USD_Price = case_when(is.na(USD_Price) ~ as.numeric(Category_alias), .default =
#   USD_Price)`.
# Caused by warning:
# ! NAs introduced by coercion
```

Guessing at some next steps, you may want to remove the numbers from the `Category_alias` column and fill the blanks (and numbers) with the previous non-missing value. We can do that like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
j |>
  mutate(
    num_category = as.numeric(Category_alias),
    USD_Price = coalesce(USD_Price, num_category),
    Category_alias = if_else(Category_alias == "" | !is.na(num_category), NA, Category_alias)
  ) |>
  select(-num_category) |>
  fill(Category_alias, .direction = "down")
#       Category_alias USD_Price
# 5350 jewelry.pendant    589.00
# 5351 jewelry.pendant    427.07
# 5352    jewelry.ring    495.21
# 5353    jewelry.ring    447.89
# 5354 jewelry.earring    804.79
# 5355 jewelry.earring     53.62
# 5356    jewelry.ring    509.59
# 5357 jewelry.earring    405.48
# 5358  jewelry.brooch    352.05
# 5359 jewelry.earring    587.67
# 5360 jewelry.pendant    158.70
# 5361    jewelry.ring    150.55
# 5362    jewelry.ring    214.48
# 5363    jewelry.ring     82.05
# 5364 jewelry.earring    280.68
# 5365 jewelry.pendant    212.19
# Warning message:
# There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
# ℹ In argument: `num_category = as.numeric(Category_alias)`.
# Caused by warning:
# ! NAs introduced by coercion
```